# can we return from a gateway while process executes in another thread in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Hi I have a situation where I want to return the response from the spring gateway while some backend processing happens in another service locator the setup I have is like this as of now .where searchGateway is the gateway and searchResultProcessor needs to be executes as asynch.

```
<int:gateway id="searchGateway" 
        service-interface="com.premise.service.integration.SearchGateway"
        default-request-channel="search-input" default-reply-channel="search-processed-result" />
    <int:header-enricher input-channel="search-input"
        output-channel="search">
        <int:header name="city" expression="payload.searchRequest.cityName"></int:header>
        <int:header name="servicetype" expression="payload.searchRequest.serviceType"></int:header>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <!-- Webservice callee Integration -->
    <int:splitter id="searchSplitter" ref="searchProductSplitter"
        method="split" input-channel="search" apply-sequence="true"
        output-channel="splittedSearch">
    </int:splitter>
    <!-- Loader or processor -->
    <int:service-activator id="searchProduct"
        input-channel="splittedSearch" ref="searchProcessor" method="process"
        output-channel="search-response">
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="4" fixed-delay="1"
            task-executor="searchExecutor"></int:poller>
    </int:service-activator>
    <!-- Aggregator -->
    <int:aggregator input-channel="search-response"
        output-channel="search-aggr-reply" expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
        send-partial-result-on-expiry="false" />
    <int:bridge input-channel="search-aggr-reply" 
        output-channel="save-search-results" />
    <!-- Process Results post comparison and send aggr response -->
    <!-- End Search activator -->
    <int:service-activator input-channel="search-aggr-reply"
        output-channel="search-processed-result" ref="searchResultEnricher"
        method="process" requires-reply="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to return from gateway method immediately and get the result somewhere later. For this purpose Spring Integration support [async gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#async-gateway).

Is it your case?

Comment: ya I am aware but my case is that I want to return from the gateway with the response but want to put the request into another queue which keeps on executing in the background on a separate thread.

Comment: The Publish-Subcribe Channel is for you

Comment: ahh silly me a typical publish subscribe scenario .. thanks a lot Artem